# Pushing a Docker image with gcloud failed

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-image, docker-engine

I'm trying to deploy a jhipster project on google cloud. 
I was able to create a docker image but I haven't been able to push it. On the google cloud SDK shell, when I run :

*gcloud docker -- push gcr.io/dimadigitallearning/openjdk-app:0.0.1*

I get this error :

*error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.28/images/gcr.io/dimadigitallearning/openjdk-app/push?tag=0.0.1: open //./pipe/docker_engine: Le fichier spécifié est introuvable. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.*

This is my first time using google cloud and docker.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem and solved it by making sure the correct docker env variables were set. To see those values (at least on Windows 7 / Docker Toolkit which includes docker-machine), do the following

```
docker-machine env default
```

As well as showing you the values to set, this command will show you how to set them easily on a windows command line:

```
@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env default') DO @%i
```

Once this is done, try your push again.